# How load json data by ajax call in jqgrid

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

By `ajax` call data fetched from server but problem is that response
should be load in `jqgrid` but not loading. In var `dataAjax  = jData.responseText;`
`dataAjax`  received data from server.

Whats wrong with that. please help

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var resData = "";
    $(".btnLoad").click((function(){
        resData = $.ajax({
               type : "POST",
               url: "/AccountUI/DataFlow/AccountDetails.html",
               dataType: "json",
               success: functioin(jData){
                   var dataAjax  = jData.responseText;         
                    return dataAjax;
               }

            });
    });

    var gridData = new Array();
    gridData = resData;     
    jQuery("#ajgrid").jqGrid({ 
            datatype: "json", 
            height: 250, 
            colNames:['AccID','AccName', 'AccBranch'], 
            colModel:[ {name:'AccID',index:'AccID', width:60, sorttype:"int"}, 
                {name:'AccName',index:'AccName', width:90}, 
                {name:'AccBranch',index:'AccBranch', width:100}             
            ], 
            multiselect : true, 
            caption : "Account Grid" 
    }); 


    for(var i=0;i<=gridData.length;i++) 
       jQuery("#ajgrid").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,gridData[i]);

});
```

Comment: In ajax callback you just return your data to nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are misunderstanding what `datatype: "json"` means. It works together with `url` option. jqGrid makes Ajax request for you and filled returned from the server data in the grid. If you don't implemented *server side paging* you should add additionally `loadonce: true` option to the grid.

So I hope that what you need is: 1) remove manual `$.ajax` call; 2) remove the loop where you fill the grid using `addRowData`; 3) add the following options to jqGrid:

```js
url: "/AccountUI/DataFlow/AccountDetails.html",
mtype: "POST",
loadonce: true,
gridview: true,
autoencode: true
```

I recommend you additionally to replace `height: 250` to `height: "auto"`. Depend on the exact format of returned data you could need to add `jsonReader` with the properties which help jqGrid to interpret the server response correctly. Probably that jqGrid could automatically detect the format of returned data.